# Spring Batch Admin - Job Monitor UI - Customization

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jobs

we are using the sample war for Job Monitor using UI which provided by the Spring Batch.
Version : spring-batch-admin-sample-1.0.0.RELEASE

Now we thought removing few unwanted menu items from the UI.

please let us know how to do that.[image: screen shot of the UI page]

Answer (score 0):

Start out by reading [The Manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/design.html) (the last part talks about 'Template Overrides' which is what you want to do). Then simply do as they say :-), put a copy of the (Freemarker) Template you want to override using the directory structure specified in the manual. If you want to change the look of the jobs view, copy the original jobs.ftl from the Spring Batch Admin jar and put it under WEB-INF/web/manager/jobs/html and start tweaking!

br
Svante